# How to flush object cache in sharepoint; programmatically

Tags: sharepoint, caching, sharepoint-2010

In sharepoint we can clear object cache from **Site Collection Administration - Site collection object cache**

Is there a way to do the same programmatically ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do the same as "Object Cache Flush" programmatically. (It uses internal objects)

But you can do the same as "Force all servers in the farm to flush their object cache" by:

```
SiteCacheSettingsWriter writer=new SiteCacheSettingsWriter(site);
writer.SetFarmCacheFlushFlag();
writer.Update();
```